# How to dynamically set width of Checkbox list bounded to a data source in a table?

Tags: html, css, web-controls, system.web.ui.webcontrols

I have a checkbox list inside a table row. The Checkboxes are equally spaced out but i want to remove the spacing between each checkbox. is this possible ? Also is it possible to text wrap labels that are too long for example "Autism Spectrum Disorder(neuro devel disorder)" I want to text wrap that. Any help would be much appreciated !

```
                    <tr>
                        <td colSpan="3" ID="tdQ29" runat="server">
                            <asp:checkboxlist id="chklDisabilities" AutoPostBack="True" RepeatLayout="Table" BorderWidth="0" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="4" Runat="server" ></asp:checkboxlist>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
```

How it looks like:
[image]

How i want it to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for this after doing some research. I just needed to change RepeatLayout to RepeatLayout="Flow"